# javascript to pass string to native objective-c

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c

I want to pass string from a button click from `html` to `ios native objective-c`. Here is my `html` with simple `javascript`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            function callVrama(vramaID) {
            window.location= "vramaWebShelves://vramaID/"+vramaID;
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <button onclick="callVrama('asdfqwer1234')">Try it</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my function in `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"content"
                                                  withExtension:@"html"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_webShelves loadRequest:requestObj];
    _webShelves.delegate = self;
}
/// some other codes

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    static NSString *urlPrefix = @"vramaWebShelves://vramaID/";

    if ([url hasPrefix:urlPrefix]) {
        NSString *vramaID = [url substringFromIndex:[urlPrefix length]];
        NSLog(@"VramasRequest: %@", vramaID);
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

What seems to be a problem?

I actually follow the tutorial from this [link](http://pablin.org/2013/08/31/interfacing-with-a-uiwebview-from-a-uiviewcontroller/) and everything work. I just not sure how to change the `js function` call from tapping on the `uiwebview` to button. Here is the `javascript` from him:

```
<script language="javascript">
            function resizeText(multiplier) {
                if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
                    document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
                }
                document.body.style.fontSize =
                parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) +
                (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
            }

            function touchStart(event) {
                sX = event.touches[0].clientX;
                sY = event.touches[0].clientY;
            }

            function touchEnd(event) {
                var parentNode = event.target.parentNode
                if ( parentNode != null && parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a" )
                    return;

                if (event.changedTouches[0].clientX == sX &&
                    event.changedTouches[0].clientY == sY) {

                    window.location = "nativeAction://hideShow";
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
            document.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, false);

            </script>
```

Comment: what the problem? `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest` not called or params not parsed ?

Comment: `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest` not call. Is there something else I need to do with `javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in those two lines:

```
[_webShelves loadRequest:requestObj];
_webShelves.delegate = self;
```

please try set `delegate` before `loadRequest`

Comment: where you create `_webShelves`, is not nil? shouldStartLoadWithRequest should be called at least once when you load content html.

Comment: I tested with another html(with different js function) it works, that means is not the ios part but something is missing in js.

Comment: maybe you should set `window.location.href`

Comment: Tried that too. Still no result.

Answer (score 0):

After reread many times and some other related test. I figure out how to get it to work. In `objective c`, replace this function:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if ([request.URL.scheme caseInsensitiveCompare:@"vramaWebShelves"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];
        static NSString *urlPrefix = @"vramaWebShelves://vramaID/";
        NSString *vramaID = [url substringFromIndex:[urlPrefix length]];
        NSLog(@"VramasRequest: %@",vramaID);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Mind the `caseInsensitiveCompare:@"vramaWebShelves"`, which is not `caseInsensitiveCompare:@"vramaWebShelves://"`, That I believed is my lack of understanding with the function.

And, nothing wrong with my `javascript` and `html`.